# Heart containers which are painful to miss?

Tags: zelda-spirit-tracks

I am finally playing through The Legend of Zelda - Spirit Tracks, and I don't want to read through any heart container guide.

Are there any containers which are a pain to specifically hunt after later in the gameplay, given I miss them on the regular playthrough?

Comment: Do you not want to read heart container guides to avoid spoilers, or just not wanting to deal with them? I'm thinking about how to answer, but don't want to be too specific if the reason you're avoiding guides is spoiler-related.

Comment: I don't have any issue dealing with guides, I want to avoid spoilers story- and gameplay wise. I want the challenge, but I don't want to invest time in the scale of hours to get the containers post-story. Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most heart containers in Spirit Tracks are pretty easily obtainable. Some backtracking might be needed to get to the right locale if you miss a container, but that time required is pretty minimal.

There are some heart containers which are actually easier if you wait until later in the game, as you'd have more items/locations available, and be more battle ready.

With that being said, there is one heart container that could be a pain to wait on until later in the game. Without being too specific to respect your request for spoilers, it involves spending a certain amount of rupees at a single location before you are awarded the heart. Buying items from this location throughout the course of the game will allow it to restock. If you wait until the end of the game to attempt this heart, you could have a lot of downtime waiting to even be able to spend more money until it is restocked. Be sure to purchase the (very small item spoiler)

> Membership Card

so that it will start tracking your rupees spent here.

Comment: That's great help. I've already seen the heat container that is 2000 rupees, but I will try to keep my rupees together if you meant another one later in the game. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kamuro It is another one. That heart container you are referring to is a one-time cost of 2000 rupees. The one I reference in the last paragraph of my answer is one that is rewarded after spending enough money on **other merchandise**. The amount needed for this one is even more than the 2000 rupee one, so keep saving up!